# Sublime Text: view tasks in namespace within Ruby code

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2

Sublime Text does a great job of showing methods available within a file (`Cmd R`) however it doesn't seem to be able to show a list of the `task` statements within a `namespace`.

Any suggestions on how you do this?